# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 5, 5], expected input[1, 32, 3, 784] to have 3 channels, but got 32 channels instead

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 5, 5], expected input[1, 32, 3, 784] to have 3 channels, but got 32 channels instead
this is my code:

````
class Conv(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    #self.flatten=nn.Flatten()
    self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=32,kernel_size=5,padding=0,stride=1)
    self.relu1=nn.ReLU()
    self.pool1=nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2)
    self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=32,kernel_size=5,padding=0,stride=1)
    self.relu2=nn.ReLU()
    self.pool2=nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2,stride=2)
    self.flatten=nn.Flatten()
    self.fc1=nn.Linear(in_features=32*4*4,out_features=128)
    self.relu3=nn.ReLU()
    self.fc2=nn.Linear(in_features=128,out_features=64)
    self.relu4=nn.ReLU()
    self.fc3=nn.Linear(in_features=64,out_features=7)
    self.logSoftmax=nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
  def forward(self,x):
    x=self.conv1(x)
    x=self.relu1(x)
    x=self.pool1(x)
    x=self.conv2(x)
    x=self.relu2(x)
    x=self.pool2(x)
    x=self.flatten(x)
    x=self.fc1(x)
    x=self.relu3(x)
    x=self.fc2(x)
    x=self.relu4(x)
    x=self.fc3(x)
    out=self.logSoftmax(x)
    return out```
````

the error is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCp05.png)

this is data's shape:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ilq.png)

please help me fix this. Thank you!!!

I tried 1 channel but still got the error

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there is a mismatch between the number of channels in your input and the weight of the first convolutional layer.

If your input data shape is [3, 784] (in the image), it means you are treating the entire image as a flat vector with 784 elements for each of the three channels. In that case, you must reshape your input data to have the appropriate shape for a 2D image with 3 channels.
here is an updated version to solve your issue

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Conv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Conv, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, padding=0, stride=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, padding=0, stride=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=32 * 4 * 4, out_features=128)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=7)
        self.logSoftmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Reshape the input to [batch_size, channels, height, width]
        x = x.view(-1, 3, 28, 28)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        out = self.logSoftmax(x)
        return out


model = Conv()


input_data = torch.randn((3,784))
print(input_data.shape)

output = model(input_data)
print(output)
```

Comment: after adjusting I still get the same error sir. Error at the conv1 layer.

Comment: @nguyensang Please provide full code of the testing code you are using. Where is the code that outputs the error?

Comment: @nguyensang the issue is with the input dimension to the code not the code it self. if your input is always 32 not 3 add this to first layer `self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=32,kernel_size=5,padding=0,stride=1)`

Comment: @nguyensang i have updated the answer after seeing the dimension of your data it should work fine now